# Create actor with default parameter value

Tags: scala, akka

Given the following actor class:

```
class MyActor(val arg: Int = 5) extends Actor {
  ...
}
```

**How can I create an instance of MyActor that uses the default value without using the [dangerous variant on Prop](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/actors.html#Dangerous_Variants)** `system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor()))`?

Both the first variant `system.actorOf(Props[MyActor])` and the second variant `system.actorOf(Props(classOf[MyActor]))` throw:

> IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on MyActor for arguments []

Which is unexpected since the class MyActor should have an empty constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `Props(new MyActor)` variant is only dangerous when you're calling it within another actor (due to closing over the enclosing actor's `this`). To overcome the danger, define a `props` factory in `MyActor`'s companion object, and specify a default parameter value for it instead of in the actor's constructor:

```
object MyActor {
  def props(arg: Int = 5): Props = Props(new MyActor(arg))
}
class MyActor(arg: Int) extends Actor {
  ...
}
```

And then

```
system.actorOf(MyActor.props())
```